# Unable to route using express and mongoose, keep getting "Type Error : req.params.user is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm stuck with routing issue for days and couldn't find where did I go wrong. I'm trying to add some fields to the users object through a form.
Here is my mongoose schema:

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

```
local            : {
    firstName    : String,
    lastName     : String,
    email        : String,
    password     : String,
    gender       : String,
    country      : String,
    position     : [{type: String}],
    operation    : String,
    userip       : String
    }
});
```

route.js:

```
app.post("/OTPmaker", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

     User.find(req.param.user_id, function(err, user){
         if(err)
                res.send(err);
            user.local.position = req.params("position");
            user.local.operation = req.params("operation");
            user.local.userip = req.params("userip");

                    user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                    });
         });
    });
```

I've got it working once but I don't know what made it to work.

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56f96c2703fb6a341ecab298"),
"local" : {
"country" : "U.S",
"gender" : "Male",
"lastName" : "KS",
"firstName" : "Balajee",
"password" : "$2a$08$Dmtf8/4lXOX7mUekRHEgGu9ItMxgFc/Ngs0NtjYcpDd9yytSSRZ8a",
"email" : "balajee41@gmail.com",
"operation" : "add",
"userip" : "11",
"position" : [
 "1",
 "2"
 ]
},
"__v" : 3
}
```

But now it isn't working. This is the error.

```
C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Neutro\app\routes.js:66
            user.local.position = req.params("position");
                                      ^

TypeError: req.params is not a function
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Neutro\app\routes.js:66:39)
    at C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Neutro\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:177:19
    at C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Neutro\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:415:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:344:13)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! neutro@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the neutro@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the neutro package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls neutro
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Neutro\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: `req.body.position` or `req.body["position"]` is the valid notation, and a body parser should put a POST in "body". But check your "POST" request is sending what you think. `console.log(req.body)` should sort that out.

Comment: This is what I'm getting when I use console.log(req.body)                                       { position: '1', operation: 'add', userip: '1' }

Comment: So `position: '1'` is **not** an array, If it were it would be `position: ['1']`. That is the reason mongoose is throwing the error. What are you trying to do? Overwrite the array data with a single element array? Or are you trying to "append" the new element to the array instead?

Comment: getting this error when I use req.body.position                                                          { position: [ '1', '2' ], operation: 'add', userip: '11' }
C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Neutro\app\routes.js:67
            user.local.position = req.body.position;
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined

Comment: This is my function for checking positions`function ckposition() {
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('otp_position');
console.log(arr);
checkedPosition.length = 0;
for (var i = 0; inputElements[i]; i++) {
if (inputElements[i].checked) {
 checkedPosition.push(inputElements[i].value);
}}
console.log(checkedPosition);
return checkedPosition;` This is the function that i've linked on onsubmit in my form `function validateIP() {
var position = ckposition();
var operation = sloperation();
var userip = saveOp();
return {
position: position,
operation: operation,
userip: userip
};
}'

Comment: I don't know why I'm not getting an array when the checked position's length is 1. @BlakesSeven

Answer (score 0):

Yes request.params is not  a function, you should be doing..

```
req.params.position;
```

Comment: C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Neutro\app\routes.js:66
            user.local.position = req.params.position;
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Neutro\app\routes.js:66:33)
    at C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Neutro\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:177:19
    at C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Neutro\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:415:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:344:13)

Comment: you need to check that your user.local is not undefined. if it is undefined and if you want it to be created in database then you would have to do something like this.

            `user.local = {};
            user.local.position = req.params("position");
            user.local.operation = req.params("operation");
            user.local.userip = req.params("userip");`

Comment: just debug `user` , as in what you are getting in the callback.

Comment: I'm getting that user.local is undefined. I'm getting user.save is not a function after following your steps  @Garg, please help.